# Visual Studio products version compatibility (eg. express, ultimate)

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to use two scenarios:

In first I would like to mix Visual Studio Community and Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

In second scenario I would like to mix Visual Studio 2013 Express and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Assuming that seniors will use Ultimate/Professional and other devs will use Community/Express:

1. Is there any differences which one will create solution? Can I create solution using Ultimate and use it with Express without any loss for Ultimate and Express versions?
2. Is there any differences which one will compile solution? If Express compile whole solution, will be any performance loss in comparison to compilation made by Ultimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VS2013**

I currently work in an environment where there are people using VS2013 Ultimate, VS2013 Pro, and VS2013 Express.  This project has been going for over a year and we haven't had any issues with managing the solution or solution compilation.

**VS2015**

I don't have any experience with VS2015 in the scenarios outlined, but based on my experience with VS2013, I can't imagine there would be any differences for your 2 questions.  FYI:  You can find a comparison of the VS2015 products and features [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx)

FWIW:
We actually had some people who were using VS2013 Express upgrade to VS2015 community and that is the only time we had an issue.  I can't seem to find what the issue was; but it was something with the way VS2015 did things.